# Can you cross a space from which a two dimensional plane is missing?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, space

If I travel through 3d space, will my travel be stopped abruptly if I encounter a 2d plane without space? That is if a 2d plane of space is missing?

You can consider every type of motion, continuous, step-wise, accelerating with an arbitrary value, or whatever, as long as you don't take refugee to 4d space.

Comment: Are you assuming that trajectories must be continuous?

Comment: does this question really make sense ?

Comment: @armand Not at all!

Comment: @Methadont This is an empirical question, and nobody is ever likely to know the answer because it certainly won't happen that a 2D-slice of space goes missing.

Comment: @Speakpigeon In the epokyrotic universe two infinite hyper volumes are separated a very small distance from each other. There is space between them. If they touch (or almost touch) a new big bang starts. What makes this different from the example above? That the gap I presume is *in* the space itself (which makes it discontinuous)? Why shouldn't it be possible that somewhere a piece of space(time) is missing? oes space *have* to be continuous? This nicely extends to Zeno's paradox.

Comment: @Methadont 1. Space and time have to be continuous, certainly if they are at all like what we think of them. If space was somehow discontinuous, then nothing could propagate across the discontinuities, and if we try to think in terms of non-propagation, then we cannot interpret the present as the continuation of the past, and what happens here as being the consequence by propagation of what happened elsewhere. - 2. Theoretical models of the universe are theoretical. Space isn't.

Comment: @Speakpigeon  "If space was somehow discontinuous, then nothing could propagate across the discontinuities" That's exactly what's my question is about. Why should a missing 2d plane matter? It has zero width. So why shouldn't be able to cross it?

Comment: @Methadont As I said, because we think of the continuity of space as necessary for physical quantities to propagate between distinct locations. This is also how general relativity works as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Yes indeed. According to GR space(time) must be smooth and continuous. On the macro level. On the smallest scales, it's not so sure. There, spacetime has to be quantized. This means a discrete spacetime. Though this can't be visualized as small disconnected chunks of spacetime.

Comment: @Speakpigeon  Is this based on Zeno's paradox and motion? I'm pretty sure physics has left the door open to spacetime being discrete or continuous - physicists don't know yet and have compatible theories (e.g. mathematics) for either case I thought. Are you asserting such from the perspective of philosophy? Do you have a metaphysics that can assert this a priori without further empirical investigation?

Comment: @Methadont "*Though this can't be visualized as small disconnected chunks of spacetime*" No, precisely. To think of discrete space as made of disconnected points requires to assume that it is somehow inside another space which is continuous. Think of the integers. You don't need to think that the set of integers is inside the set of reals. And you "move" from one integer to the next without having to "move through" real numbers.

Comment: @JKusin Please quote the part of what I say that you are referring to. I am essentially talking from the point of view of common sense. Seems to work.

Comment: @Speakpigeon But if the points ar very tiny 2d space bubbles it can be visualized as such. Likewise, you can imagine two regions of 3d space consisting of a huge collection of these. In between these collections an empty flat 2d region can be present. Which is actually part of the 3d space containing the bubbles.  The very division of these bubbles defines this flat 2d space (or very thin 3d space).  Don't ask how this division comes about, just imagine it.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Here: "As I said, because we think of the *continuity of space as necessary for physical quantities to propagate* between distinct locations. This is also how general relativity works as far as I understand it." The continuity of space as *necessary* for propagation. That is a very strong claim. I have not seen something that forceful. It seems to make some assumptions I'm not sure are *necessary*.

Comment: @JKusin 1. "*That is a very strong claim*" Not a all. My claim is that this is how we think of space and time, not at all that this is how space and time really are, or even that space and time really exist to begin with. - 2. "*I'm not sure are necessary*" Excellent. As long as you cannot explain why they would be false.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Ok so you are saying within GR, we need continuity for space and motion to make sense?

Comment: @JKusin Yes, although maybe not continuity as usually understood. Most people are a bit slipshod about their vocabulary and assume implicitly all sorts of things so I would only bet on the concept necessary to make sense of any physical theory, including therefore GR, but I won't take responsibility for the vocabulary people use to identify said concepts.

Comment: The scenario is impossible. You can make up any fancy SF answer you want and write a story about it. I have read a good few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I travel through 3d space, will my travel be stopped abruptly if I encounter a 2d plane without space? That is if a 2d plane of space is missing?

The 2D missing plane is an interruption of continuity in the 3D space you are moving in, so essentially your body just disappears as it moves out of the 3D space. It doesn't reappear on the other side because continuity has been interrupted.

For all intent and purposes, the part of your body out of your side of the 3D space would have disappeared altogether. It would be as if your body had just lost one half.

If you stayed only a few seconds half-in, half-out, then some of your blood for example would keep moving out of 3D space and disappearing. Your blood pressure would drop very quickly and you would probably die very quickly. An eyeball half-out would also empty like a glass of water tipped 90° to one side.

If you kept moving, for example from inertia, you would just completely disappear never to come back.

It all depends of course on what you mean exactly by a missing bit of space, but this is what would happens if this bit of space really no longer existed.

Maybe the really interesting question rather is what would happen to space itself. If space does not exist in itself, that is, if space is an epiphenomenon, then it cannot go missing either, so that would make your hypothetical scenario totally impossible.

If there is, however, something like the fabric of space, then such a space might conceivably be inside another space, for example a 4 or 5D space or whatever. In such a case, I think the effect of a missing bit in it would broadly be the same as the one described above.

The more plausible situation, however, is that spacetime as we think of it, including in General Relativity, is essentially a model based on empirical experience, empirical experience we have no means of deciding whether it is complete of reality. So, we can only answer this sort of question on the basis of what we understand, i.e., on the basis of our model, and scenarios that are counterfactual to our model, as this one is, have almost zero plausibility. The answer can only be as good as our model and our model is most plausibly false of reality, even if it is true of our empirical experience.

Comment: Why do you think it's most plausibly false of reality? Why do we have no means of deciding whether it's complete of reality?

Comment: @Methadont All we have is empirical experience. So how could you possibly decide that it is complete of reality? We can always assume it is, but that may not be true. For practical purposes, we assume it is. This is not even a rational decision. We just do it. And, broadly, it works. But science demonstrated that our trust was misplaced. Reality appears to be much, much weirder than anything anyone anticipated.

Comment: We may not have empirical evidence, but why is this needed to ascertain something (or falsify)? The atom seems 100% certain to exist. It *is* 100% certain it exists. Or what about elementary particles? More objective than them it can't get. There may be a smaller subdivision of the Standard Model ones, but more elementary it can't get (except for searching ways to circumvent their supposed point-likeness). The eventual two really elementary particles *must* be the most elementary.

Comment: @Methadont "*The atom seems 100% certain to exist. It is 100% certain it exists.*" Science itself says certainty is a psychological state.

Comment: But it *is* a certainty.

Comment: @Methadont Yours. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should be unable to reach anything on the other side of the plane.  Whether you are stopped abruptly is not clear, as there are issues revolving around the underlying metric of the space (e.g if things shrink as you approach the missing plane, you may never stop, as the perceived distance to it is always 'further away').

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "stopped abruptly".
The question can be answered from multiple perspectives:

The notion of a continuous, smooth space in physics is tied to the mathematical term of a smooth manifold. However, there are generalizations like connected space, which is the simplest mathematical
structure with geometrical meaning. Though in mathematics, nothing prevents you from defining discrete spaces. Connected Spaces don't even require a metric, which is a function giving a sense of "distance" to a space, to be defined on it. Topology is the mathematical theory in which very primitive notions of space can be studied.

So when is a space no longer continuous and smooth in physics, such that you can be "stopped abruptly"? Well, "singularities" are what capturing this best;

In Relativity, gravitational singularities are 0-dimensional points in spacetime, where all geodesics end. Space and Time are "ending" at this point. The specifics are clarified by the Penrose-Hawking Singularity Theorems.

In String Theory, there are generalizations to higher dimensional singularities, like 1D Cosmic String and 2D Domain Walls. ​

To the best of current physical understanding, hitting any singularity would  imply you ceasing from existence.
There are theoretical debates whether the information content of your body would be re-constructible  in
the case of 0-dimensional gravitational singularities  (Black Hole Information Paradoxon).

More generalized spoken from the perspective of the perspective of Modal Realism, none of the above mentioned results are logical necessities though and you could axiomatically probably construct logically possible worlds where other outcomes happen when you hit "the end" of a connected space.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the question you may consider the analogue with two dimensions less: Can one travel along the real line when one point is removed?

I consider the problem underdetermined, it needs more context to be well-posed.